# xcode jumps a method and finish

Tags: ios, c, xcode, xcode8

im new at coding with Xcode but strangely it jumps some instructions and finish the program without printing the results. the **find_track** method is not printing the position of the song and skips to end. the code can be build and has "apparently"no error (it comes from a C coding book). Anyone familiar with Xcode who can help ?

```
char tracks[][80] = {"my spirit","code songs"};
void find_track(char search_for[]) { 
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    if (strstr(tracks[i],search_for)){
        printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
char search_for[80];
printf("Search for: \n");
fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
find_track(search_for); 
return 0;
}
** Program ended with exit code: 0 // exit message from Xcode
```

Comment: Remember that `fgets` retains a trailing newline as part of the string, so the text will not match any substring unless you remove it.

Comment: add `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = 0;` before call your function.

Comment: You have tagged this as `iOS` - are you running this code on an iOS device or simulator? If so, stdout and stdin are /dev/null

Comment: It is called from main(). the input is ( e.g  songs )the expected output is the position and name of the song. 
@WeatherVane i'll dig in on what you say because using **scanf()** works with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` leave newline (enter key) in the buffer. You can easily test it

```
int main(void)
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: \n");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    printf("%s", search_for);

    for (size_t i=0; i<strlen(search_for); i++)
    {
        printf ("%X - %c\n", search_for[i], search_for[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input `my spirit` from terminal output will be

```
0x6D - m
0x79 - y
0x20 -  
0x73 - s
0x70 - p
0x69 - i
0x72 - r
0x69 - i
0x74 - t
0x0A -
```

Final `0x0A` is '\n' char: newline.

Passing directly it to `find_track` function `strstr` will try to match that char too.
So simple solution is to remove that char:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = { "my spirit", "code songs" };

void find_track(char search_for[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for) != NULL)
        {
            printf("Track %i: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    char search_for[80];
    printf("Search for: \n");
    fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
    printf("%s", search_for);

    // Remove newline
    search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0';

    find_track(search_for);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you do `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = 0;` and not `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = '\0';`? Although they are same, I feel it's better to assign a character in a character array (for readability)

Comment: @babon and why not `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = 0x00;` ;) No real reason.Probably I'm lazy and `1` char is better then `4`

Comment: Solved the doubt clear and efficient, thanks a lot @LPs

Comment: @babon BTW `sizeof '\0'` is 4, not 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right but what I meant by "same" was that eventually `0` would be stored in the array`search_for`